# Passing a variable from another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
import shutil


def listdirectory():
    global computername
    computername = input("What is the computer name? ")
    completepathlist = fr"\\{computername}\C$\Users"
    return os.listdir(completepathlist)

def username():
    global completepath
    global usernameinput
    usernameinput = input("What is the user name? ")
    completepath = fr"\\{computername}\C$\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google"

def programrunningcheck():
    password = input("What is your password? ")
    command = "taskkill /s " + str(computername) + " /u " + str(usernameinput) + " /p " +password+ " /im chrome.exe"
    print(command)
    os.system(command)

def deletegoogleapp():
    shutil.rmtree(completepath)

#Functions being called
print(listdirectory())
username()
programrunningcheck()
deletegoogleapp()
```

Everything works up until `deletegoogleapp` function is called and receive a

> \\DESKTOP-62A8SSM\C$\Users\"**function username at
>   0x010C8B28**\AppData\Local\Google

looks to be not passing the variable `completepath` from another function to the `googleapp` function.

Comment: my suggestion would be that you rewrite what you have done without all these functions, when that is working you can wrap that into a single function call. if you need every variable to be global, do you really need functions in the way you have attempted to use them?

Comment: I agree may not be best written - I'm new to programing and self teaching so I am sure I have a lot of bad practice's

Comment: The `username` variable used by `fr"\\{computername}\C$\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google"` is the name of the **function** the statement is in — i.e. `function username at 0x010C8B28`. I think you want `usernameinput`.

Comment: You could either use global variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/423596/6212957 OR you could pass previous function as a parameter to get it's return value `lastfunction( secondfunction() )`

Comment: ahed87 - would love to see another example of writing this in one function - I would love to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed original issue with var and made some other coding change

```
import os
import shutil
import time


def listdirectory():
    global computername
    computername = input("What is the computer name? ")
    completepathlist = fr"\\{computername}\C$\Users"
    return os.listdir(completepathlist)

def username():
    global completepath
    usernameinput = input("What is the user name? ")
    completepath = fr"\\{computername}\C$\Users\{usernameinput}\AppData\Local\Google"

def programrunningcheck():
    print("We need your credentials to kill chrome")
    techuser = input("What is your username? ")
    techpassword = input("What is your password? ")
    command = "taskkill /s " + str(computername) + " /u " + str(techuser) + " /p " +(techpassword)+ " /im chrome.exe"
    time.sleep(5)
    print(command)
    os.system(command)

def deletegoogleapp():
    shutil.rmtree(completepath)

#Functions being called
print(listdirectory())
username()
programrunningcheck()
deletegoogleapp()
```

Comment: Can you [edit] this and add how it solved your problem? That will help others with a similar problem.

Comment: Fixes were my variable for username did not match my string name for username - bigger issue was it was passing the inputed username to taskkill - now prompts for separate account that has remote admin rights to kill task on that pc

Answer (score 0):

You need so store the return value of `username`, right now, you are passing nothing to `deletegoogleapp`. So you can do:

```
u <- username()
programrunningcheck()
deletegoogleapp(u)
```

This should work given the path `u` returned is valid.

Answer (score 0):

change you'r function username:

```
global completepath
global usernameinput

def username(self):
    usernameinput = input("What is the user name? ")
    completepath = fr"\\{computername}\C$\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google"
```